# AWS CLI SNS push notifications to my iOS app works, but how can I play a different sound or change the badge number?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, command-line-interface

I'm using the Amazon Web Service Command Line Interface to send a push notification to my iOS app using the command:

```
aws sns publish --target-arn \"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:545678945607:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/MyApp/lk4ggss56-2F29-3r55-6Qw2-dsd4sad4s5a\" --message \"hello!\"
```

This works fine, but is it possible to also pass info for playing a non-defualt sound or changing the app's badge number using the AWS CLI?

When sending a message to Apple's APNs directly you're able to post a json block similar to this to change the sound played or badge number:

```
{
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : {
      "title" : "testMessage",
      "body" : "Hi!"
    },
    "sound" : "0546.aiff",
    "badge": "100"
  }
}
```

This is all new to me, any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**SOLVED**

**Update: Solution that worked for me:**

Used this command:

```
aws sns publish --target-arn \"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:545678945607:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/MyApp/lk4ggss56-2F29-3r55-6Qw2-dsd4sad4s5a\" --message-structure \"json\"  --message file://aps.json
```

The contents of the file named "aps.json" is:

```
{"default":"This is the default Message","APNS_SANDBOX":"{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"New push notification.\", \"badge\" : 9,\"sound\" :\"0546.aiff\"}}"}
```

Which sets the badge number, and uses the custom sound included in my app.

Comment: Did you try sending the whole json block as the message? e.g. put it in a aps.json file, then `aws sns publish --message file://aps.json`

Comment: @jingz  That's a good idea. Unfortunately, it just shows the whole json block text in the push notification that is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

Used this command:

```
aws sns publish --target-arn \"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:545678945607:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/MyApp/lk4ggss56-2F29-3r55-6Qw2-dsd4sad4s5a\" --message-structure \"json\"  --message file://aps.json
```

The contents of the file named "aps.json" is:

```
{"default":"This is the default Message","APNS_SANDBOX":"{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"New push notification.\", \"badge\" : 9,\"sound\" :\"0546.aiff\"}}"}
```

Which set the badge number, and uses the custom sound included in my app.

Windows:

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:123412341234:some-topic" --message-structure json --message '{\"default\":\"This is the default Message\",\"test\": \"value\"}'
```

Comment: Bonus kudos for anyone that can this to work on the Windows command line with the JSON embedded directly, instead of having to pass it in a file.  :)